# AS3 HitTest gotoAndPlay instead of removeChild

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hittest

I have a HitTestObject that will remove the movieClip(enemy) when hit with a bullet.

This is the code:

```
if (hitTestObject(bulletTarget)) {
    //remove this from the stage if it touches a bullet
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
    _root.removeChild(this);
    //also remove the bullet and its listeners
    _root.bulletContainer.removeChild(bulletTarget);
    bulletTarget.removeListeners();
    //up the score
    _root.score += 5;
}
```

But instead of removing it immediately, I want the Movieclip(enemy) to play the next frame, which is an animation of it exploding, and once the explosion has happened it should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me!

I changed

```
_root.removeChild(this);
```

to

```
this.gotoAndPlay(2);
```

and then at the end of my explosion clip I added

```
this.parent.removeChild(this);
```